# How to create a Range object with same area, but different initial (top-left) cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I created a 'RefEdit' user form to create a new range object based on the user's input. Now, I need to create another Range object which refers to the same column(s), but to different predetermined rows. The new range object needs to maintain same area (same amount of rows and columns).

For example:

- user selects `Range("J12:L14")`
- There is a predetermined initial (top-left) row: Row number 5
- So, I need to create another range object which refers to ("J5:L7")

I have no idea to solve this. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Range.Resize property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) to start at your desired cell `Cells(RowNo, SelRng.Column)` and resize it to the same size of the other range `SelRng`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim SelRng As Range
    Set SelRng = Range("J12:L14")

    Dim RowNo As Long
    RowNo = 5

    Dim NewRng As Range
    Set NewRng = Cells(RowNo, SelRng.Column).Resize(SelRng.Rows.Count, SelRng.Columns.Count)

    Debug.Print NewRng.Address(False, False) '<-- J5:L7

End Sub
```